# Is it possible to include abs() in the objective function to be solved by pyomo solver?

Tags: python, pyomo

I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: Cannot load a SolverResults object with bad status: error "
```

whenever I use `abs()` function in the objective function.

Comment: Which solver are you trying to use? Some solvers like Ipopt require the constraints/objective to be continuous and twice differentiable and therefore do not support `abs()`.

Comment: Thank you Bethany Nicholson , it makes sense. I added a constraint to replicate the work of abs() in my optimization problem. It worked for me.

Comment: Just be careful since adding a constraint on the part that you want to get the absolute value will only forbid to find a negative solution. I'll post a workaround for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before beginning, I will use the words "non-negative" and "non-positive" instead of "positive" and "negative". This is because that in Pyomo, there is a distinction between the two, it is that "positive" and "negative" domains *exclude* 0, while "non-positive" and "non-negative" include it).

Suppose that you have the following objective function:

```
def obj_f(model):
    return abs(model.x)
```

where `model.x` is a variable in your model that can take positive and negative values.

In order to make your model work, you can split `model.x` into two variables, let's say `model.x_pos` and `model.x_neg`. This means you will have a variable for the positive part of `model.x` (`model.x_pos`) and another variable for the negative part of `model.x` (`model.x_neg`).

`model.x_pos` can only take non-negative values and `model.x_neg` can only take non-positive values. So, `model.x` can be transformed into `model.x_pos + model.x_neg`. You will have to add constraints to make sure that `model.x_pos` is always non-negative and to make sure that `model.x_neg` is always non-positive. This can be done by setting the domain when you create the variable, or by adding more constraints to your model.

This way, you can formulate your objective function this way:

```
def obj_f(model):
    return model.x_pos - model.x_neg
```

(Note: Since the `model.x_neg` variable is already negative or 0, we have to use the `-` sign in front of it to make it positive)

This should be the equivalent of using an `abs()` function in your objective function.